# Bounties awarded by a deleted user

Tags: discussion, voting, bounty, accepted-answer, deleted-accounts

As far I know, if a user is deleted, then all changes made by the user's up/down votes in everyone's reputation are reverted.

What happens with reputation due to answers accepted by the deleted user, and by bounties awarded by this user to someone?

Comment: A related post on [meta.se]: [Are bounties given by deleted users maintained or deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332919)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Accepted answers and bounties are transferred to the Community user.

You can see the list [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=bounties&sort=offered).