# Question on the Retaining or Forfeiture of Bounty Points When the Awarding User is Removed

Tags: support, bounty, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

My question is: If User A awards User B a bounty, say 500 points, and later on, User A either requests to be removed or is removed (i.e., ``User was removed''), does User B retain those 500 bounty points from User A, or are they taken from User B?

Comment: This [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224482/will-bounty-rolled-back-if-user-removed-or-suspended) is old but I think no further changes were made. So, bounties won't be rolled back.

Comment: @Ak19 The wording of that post confuses me. Does not ``bounties will never be refunded'' imply that they have at some point been removed?

Comment: Yeah, its confusing to me too. Now I think that post is about the case when the awarder's account gets deleted or suspended. Good question.

Comment: Related older post on this meta: [Bounties awarded by a deleted user](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11690).

Comment: @Martin Sleziak So it appears that an individual can work hard at answering a hard problem, be awarded the bounty, in some cases quite large, only to have it taken away at some point in the future, merely because the user who awarded the points (perhaps years prior) is no longer affiliated with the site. Seems like an injustice here. Thank you for your valuable comment.

Comment: @mlchristians Maybe I have somehow misread the linked posts, but as far as I can tell, reputation points from bounties are *not* taken away if the user who awarded the bounty was deleted. This is explicitly stated [in Asaf Karagila's answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11690/bounties-awarded-by-a-deleted-user/11691#11691). Or Glorfindel's answer here: [Are bounties given by deleted users maintained or deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332919#332952)

Comment: @Martin Sleziak Many thanks again. I wish the links I have read up to this point would have said something short and simple, such as in your comment, ``reputation points from bounties are *not* taken away if the user who awarded the bounty was deleted.''